# Android Tabhost inside another Tabhost

Tags: android

I created a tabhost in main_activity, inside the tabhost, i created another tabhost. Is it possible to create a tabhost inside another tabhost. Whenever i do so and run the code it shows a message as unfortunately your project has stooped and some error messages.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookings_tab);
    sPref=this.getSharedPreferences("REAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    session_type = sPref.getString("SESSION_TYPE", "");
    session_email = sPref.getString("SESSION_UID","");

    //TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

     final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Packages");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("Packages");
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Package_lis.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    // Tab for Songs
    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Other.Serv");        
    songspec.setIndicator("Other.Serv");
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Extraservices.class);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    TabSpec equip = tabHost.newTabSpec("Organizer");        
    equip.setIndicator("Organizer");
     Intent equipmen = new Intent(this, Orgtab.class);
     equip.setContent(equipmen);
```

In the above code Orgtab.class is another tabhost activity but it is not working.

```
                  **Error message:**
10-21 14:17:12.483: D/AndroidRuntime(785): Shutting down VM
10-21 14:17:12.501: W/dalvikvm(785): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Orgtab}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Package_lis}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40de2ba8 is not valid; is your activity running?
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Package_lis}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40de2ba8 is not valid; is your activity running?
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Orgtab.onCreate(Orgtab.java:87)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  ... 18 more
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40de2ba8 is not valid; is your activity running?
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Package_lis$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(Package_lis.java:187)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Package_lis.onCreate(Package_lis.java:141)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-21 14:17:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: Could your share your code please?

Comment: Please also add the error message and the logcat you are talking about.

Comment: i have shared the code,it uses activity class, i dont need fragment example

Comment: added the logcat message

Comment: I do not think it is a problem with your tabs directly. The log mentions a different error with a dialog: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40de2ba8 is not valid; is your activity running? at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Package_lis$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(Package_lis.java:187)

Comment: what does that mean,how can i rectify it.

Comment: if i am using a single tabhost its working fine but if i call another tabhost or tabwidget whatever it is, it is not working

Comment: TabSpec equip = tabHost.newTabSpec("Organizer");        
    equip.setIndicator("Organizer");
     Intent equipmen = new Intent(this, Orgtab.class);
     equip.setContent(equipmen);

Comment: in that Orgtab.class is using a tabhost

Answer (score 0):

i googled around and i found the `tabhost can be added in fragment`. so it may possible to add a tab host inside tabhost. but it is possible that inner tabhost may not be responsive to swipe so you can try creating `custom tabhost` as inner tabhost.

Have you seen this? it should help you out.

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/